# PHP Facebook - My own Click handler on Facebook Login button

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use a combination of JS-SDK and PHP for my Facebook API implementation. What I would like to do is, attach my custom handler when someone clicks on the following:

```
<fb:login-button size="medium">
  Connect with Facebook
</fb:login-button>
```

I know I can use a static image with the same facebook logo and wrap it in a `<a>` with my javascript code, but I would really like to use the fbml button because it can scale so well and the text in the button can be easily manipulated. I would like to avoid copying the entire CSS and duplicating the effort also if I can.

In other words, I would like something like this:

```
<script>
function doLogin() {
window.open('login.php', 'Login to FB);
}
</script>
...
<fb:login-button size="medium" onClick="doLogin();">
  Connect with Facebook
</fb:login-button>
```

Is this at all possible or am I SOL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this at all possible or am I SOL?

The latter. Even if it were possible it's against Facebook's TOS to imitate, let alone exactly reproduce their graphics.

Comment: Not imitating any functionality. Simply want to use my own login.php which I can tie back for analytic purposes. And all login.php does is use header redirect to facebook's own auth dialog.

Comment: I said you can't imitate **graphics**. If you want to know when someone logs in just *FB.Event.subscribe* to *auth.login*.

Comment: ^^^ that's if you use JS to login. If you are redirecting to login, just create your own button and then redirect after doing your analytics.